# NHibernate not saving record though query is getting printed

Tags: c#, nhibernate, save

I'm new to NHibernate (I've done Hibernate in Java without any problem) and facing a strange problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and created a console project. I created a "Service-based Database" (I attached a screenshot).

Here are my files:

**hibernate.cfg.xml** (Copy Always, Embedded Resource) and made sure that it exists in Debug folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
 <session-factory>    
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>    
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\NHibernateTest.mdf;
      </property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <mapping assembly="NHibernateConsoleProject"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Contact.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateConsoleProject" namespace="NHibernateConsoleProject">
<class name="Contact" table="Contact">
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"/>
<property name="LastName" column="LastName"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Contact.cs**

```
namespace NHibernateConsoleProject
{
public class Contact
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
}
```

**NHibernateHelper.cs**

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using System.Reflection;

namespace NHibernateConsoleProject
{
public sealed class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

    private static void OpenSession()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
        SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if (SessionFactory == null)
            NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();

        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public static void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if (SessionFactory != null)
            SessionFactory.Close();
    }
}    
}
```

**And my program**

```
using NHibernate;
using System;

namespace NHibernateConsoleProject
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();

        contact.FirstName = "Ashutosh";
        contact.LastName = "Pandey";
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

        session.Save(contact);
        session.Flush();

        transaction.Commit();

        session.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Saved...");
    }
}
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = 'Ashutosh' [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 'Pandey' [Type: String (4000)]
Saved...
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I executed query manually to insert the record, it get inserted. I read the inserted record with following program and it worked, **Insert is not working**.

**ReadContact.cs**

```
using NHibernate;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NHibernateConsoleProject
{
class ReadContacts
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();

        IList<Contact> contacts = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Contact)).List<Contact>();

        foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contact.FirstName + " , " + contact.LastName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

http://postimg.org/image/imuz6mz5d/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `session.Flush();`

When using transactions, the commit flushes all.

Comment: :( didn't work.  I've created a local Service-based database(without SQL Server Management Studio). The database is listed in solution explorer. I double clicked on it and checking the data. There is another database in the bin folder. I'm thinking whether these two copies are the culprit here. Although the database listed in solution explorer has Copy to output directory set to Copy always

Comment: Change the attachdbfilename in de configuration to a fixed path, then you are sure the same db-file is used

Comment: Hi Frank, I checked for both the databases, even started Visual Studio 2012 as administrator, but the error is same :(
I attached the project on this url (it is virus free as my anti-virus says)  [   http://tbf.me/a/BxT5xZ   ]
Please if you have some of your precious time, please tell me what could be wrong

Comment: The .mdf file is part of your solution and every time it is build, it overwrites the version in the debug or release folder. Set the property from 'copy always' to 'copy if newer' (see http://picpaste.com/Capture-7bbvBaW4.PNG). I Also noted in the hmb there is a different writing for your id generation. It should be `   <id name="Id"  type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in Server Explorer you're looking into the same database as you insert into? There's nothing wrong with your code and record should be inserted as there were no error. This should mean that you're using another database. Have a look at `bin\Debug` folder (or whatever your output folder is) and make sure that you're checking that database in Server Explorer.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the source code. I checked it on my machine and everything works OK (and I see inserted records). The records must be inserted as you didn't get any exception and after saving entity got a new id.

The issue may be that NHibernateTest.mdf file in your project is always copied to the output dir. Please try to change property `Copy To Output Directory` to `Do not copy` and see if that help (right click on file in solution -> `Properties` -> `Copy To Output Directory`). And, as I said before, please make sure that database in your `Data Connection` in Visual Studio points to database in `bin\Debug` folder. g

Comment: Hi Alexander, I checked for both the databases, even started Visual Studio 2012 as administrator, but the error is same :( I attached the project on this url (it is virus free as my anti-virus says) [ tbf.me/a/BxT5xZ ] Please if you have some of your precious time, please tell me what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your effort, I solved this issue with this line in my code:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

For my database, i use (properties of my database):

Build Action:  Content

Copy to Output:  Copy always